# Чем ограничено количество тасков / потоков выполнения?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Чем ограничено количество тасков / потоков ?

Почему я не могу выполнять работу например в 1000 тасках / потоков

Почему это бессмыслица выполнять в 1000 потоков ?

```
int maxThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2
Console.WriteLine(maxThreads);
```

Получаю 64

Т.е. я ограничен 64 потоками выполнения ?

Я запускал так, казалось быстрее xD

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    new Thread(() => Algoritm(j)).Start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    Task.Run(() => Algoritm(j));
}
```

Comment: Ограничение может быть от операционной системы, а так каждый поток требует ресурсов и переключение контекста между потоками тоже стоит ресурсы. Поэтому, считается, что эффективнее всего создавать потоков не больше чем количество ядер * 2. Хотя вы можете больше создать

Comment: Т.е. даже когда какие то софты покупаешь, которые якобы там в 300 потоков могут работать, это всё бестолковый маркетинг и рационально количество ядер * 2 ?

Comment: Именно так.....

Comment: Переключение контекстов между задачами - очень дорогая задача (как на уровне языка программирования и его абстракций, так и на уровне ОС, не только windows), поэтому чем больше вы потоков запустите -- тем больше тратите времени процессора на это бесполезное переключение, а не на реальную работу. Об этом хорошо сказано в ответе Kromster - в примере про шиномонтажников.

Comment: Не вполне понятно, почему вы считаете, что количество потоков или тем более тасков чем-то ограничено. И выполнять работу в десятках тысайч тасков вовсе не бессмысленно, особенно если ваша задача не CPU-bound.

Comment: [Некоторые вопросы о многопоточности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1105232/179763) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравый смысл.
Вы можете заказать 64 шиномонтажникам поменять 64 колеса. Каждый будет при деле. А можете заказать и 6400 колес поменять одновременно, и они будут большую часть времени между ними метаться, практически не выполняя полезной работы. Точно так же и с другими компьютерными ресурсами (обычно под ними понимается CPU, но может быть и Диск и GPU). Ниже речь о CPU-ограниченных задачах.

Откуда взялась цифра "количество_ядер * 2"?
Насколько мне известно, число "2" получено эмпирически. Т.е. ядро может выполнять примерно 2 потока поочередно, пока один ждет что-то из кеша или памяти, например, в это время второй может производить вычисления (см. Hyper-threading). Когда-то больше, когда-то меньше, но обычно - 2.

Имеет ли смысл стартовать 300 потоков?
Зависит от типа процесса и архитектуры программы. Например, вам может быть нужно получать отклик от удаленной системы, вы отправляете запрос и .. долго долго ждёте. То есть вы можете отправить 300 запросов и только потом начнут приходить какие-то ответы. Выделять для этого 300 потоков может быть не оптимальным архитектурным решением, но иногда это проще и лучше масштабируется, чем переписывать программу на асинхронную/заявочную работу. (Заметьте, в этом месте задача перестала быть CPU-ограниченной) Тут в качестве примера можно привести ОС - грубо говоря, она стартует каждую программу в своем потоке, и каждый поток 99% времени бездействует.

Comment: Hyper-threading тут ни при чём: если его включить, то каждое ядро "видно" со стороны ОС как два. Тут дело в среднем по больнице проценте блокирующих операций, вроде чтения файлов с диска.

Comment: @PavelMayorov HT по умолчанию везде включен, емнип. Почему HT "умножает" число ядер на 2, а не на 3, к примеру? Блокирующие операции тут тоже кажутся не при чем, т.к. разговор о CPU, где даже одна синхронная дисковая операция - это чуть ли не сотни тысяч тактов.

Comment: Потому что оно так устроено. И нет, HT не включен на тех процах где его нету.

Answer (score 2):

> Я запускал так, казалось быстрее xD

В приведённом фрагменте кода вы только **запускаете** потоки и задачи, но **не ждёте их завершения**. Таким образом вы можете и миллион потоков/задач запустить и они моментально "выполнятся", это абсолютно ничего не говорит об эффективности одновременного запуска потоков/задач.

Допускаю, что вы привели просто не весь код, но в случае с многопоточностью и асинхронностью критически важно, чтобы код был корректно написан, иначе можно легко получить абсолютно не релевантные результаты.

А по сути дела - нужно смотреть, какой код вы выполняете в потоках/задачах, насколько он "тяжёлый", что именно он делает - тяжёлые вычисления или он просто ждёт окончания ввода/вывода, соответственно нужно грамотно делить работу на части и использовать либо многопоточность (в разумных пределах, чтобы все ресурсы не ушли на постоянное переключение между потоками) для тяжёлых вычислительных задач, либо асинхронность для задач, упирающихся в ожидание завершения операций.

Answer (score 1):

1. Планировщик тратит на переключение контекста потока 1/3 выделенного ему кванта, о чём пишет Д.Рихтер в своей книжке "..для профессионалов". Соответственно полезное время обратно-пропорционально количеству потоков, но только в том случае, если эти потоки выполняют одну задачу. Если-же каждый поток занимается своим делом, то расходы на их переключение вполне окупаются. ООО-ядра с гипертредингом не напрягаясь способны обрабатывать не более 4-х потоков за раз при условии, что в коде будут присутствовать не только целочисленные инструкции CPU, но и активно задействован FPU, на котором исполняются команды SIMD (AVX/SSE/MMX etc). Внутри одного ядра, CPU и FPU имеют разные блоки Execute (см.микро-архитектуру), и в большинстве случаях FPU простаивает на 70-80%.
2. Системы класса Win выделяют для каждого потока макс. 1 Мб стековой памяти. Это накладывает ограничение на общее их кол-во. Например, пространство памяти юзера на системах х32 занимает нижнюю половину до 0x80000000, т.е. 2 гигабайт из четырёх. Если каждый поток затребует от этой памяти по 1 Мб, то получается, что её резерва хватит всего на 2000 потоков. Однако на практике, тред возбуждает исключение "Exсeption_Stack_Overflow" (переполнение) уже на 256 Кбайтах, что увеличивает общее число в 4 раза = 8000. На системах х64 такого ограничения нет.

Comment: `Если-же каждый поток занимается своим делом, то расходы на их переключение вполне окупаются.` это вы про 8000 потоков в процессе? Просто не понятен контекст.

Comment: Здесь 8 и даже 2000 тредов - эти чисто в теории. Расходы окупаются в случае, если к примеру, одной задаче нужно просканировать 65536 портов на удалённом узле, и мы параллелим их на 4 диапазона по 16384. То-есть на одном ядре поток(А) сканирует порты 0-16384, поток(В) озадачен портами 16385-32768, и т.д. Соответственно, для процессора с 32-ядрами получаем ещё меньший диапазон для каждого потока: `32*4=128 --> 65536/128=512` портов на тред.

Comment: я просто советую внести ясность в ответ, так как сейчас может возникнуть впечатление, что если у вас есть задачи на 8000 потоков, что эти 8000 будут оправданы не взирая на количество ядер.

Comment: Я бы так же поменял 1 и 2 пункт местами, т.к. 2-й гораздо более субстантивен, в то время как 1-й теряет актуаьность на 64-битных системах (не так ли?)

Comment: `Я бы так же поменял 1 и 2 пункт местами` - поправил.